Analyzing Range of Features for Classification
I have developed a classifier with 5 ordinal classes, and I’m looking to do a detailed analysis on the range of values required for each class (1 through 5).
For example, I want to understand how a feature like column A (with a value range of 5-10) combined with other features, influences the model’s prediction of it as a certain class.
While we’ve been using SHAP for feature importance analysis, we need to dig deeper given that we’re working with app activity data. Specifically, we need to determine the thresholds or amount of each feature needed to transition from one class to another (e.g., 5 more likes for a certain content will transition a user from class 1 to class 2, or class 2 to class 3).
Our primary goal is to gain actionable insights that would allow us to move users from a lower class to a higher one (e.g., from class 1 to class 4). This information will help us make improvements to our app or marketing strategies.
